# Media folder not working properly & Images not being saved - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-media

I am trying to add images to a post. (Using Django v3.2.5)

root_directory/settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
...
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

root_directory/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('index.urls')),
    path('app2/', include('app2.urls')),
    path('app3/', include('app3.urls')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

app3/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post_Picture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images/")
    caption = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

app3/forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post_Picture

class PostPicForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post_Picture
        fields = ('title', 'image', 'caption')
        labels = {
            'Title': '',
            'Caption': '',      
        }
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Title your post'}),
            'caption': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Anything extra you want to add?'}),
        }
```

app3/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Post_Picture
from .forms import PostPicForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages

def your_home(request):
    friend_posts = Post_Picture.objects.all()
    return render(request, "app3/your_home.html", {
        'friend_posts': friend_posts,
    })

def post_pic(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostPicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('post_pic?submitted=True')         

    else:
        form = PostPicForm()
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
    return render(request, 'app3/post_pic.html', {'form': form, 'submitted': submitted})
```

app3/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('your_home', views.your_home, name='your-home'),
    path('post_pic', views.post_pic, name='post_pic'),
]
```

pip installed stuff:

```
$ pip freeze
asgiref==3.5.2
Django==3.2.5
django-ckeditor==5.9.0
django-js-asset==2.0.0
Pillow==9.3.0
pytz==2022.6
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.3
```

I did create the media folder but it didn't work - it didn't make the "image/" directory.
During the submission process of posting pictures, it showed no error. I knew it wouldn't show the image on the website but, with that code, I'm pretty sure it should've shown the image in the admin area, but it didn't.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: see view part of the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I just had to change the form variable to:


form = PostPicForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)